FileZilla's libfilezilla component won't build due to missing GnuTLS
I am attempting to build FileZilla 3 from source according to the steps here:
https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Compiling_FileZilla_3_under_Windows
I got successfully all the way to the Building libfilezilla section:
cd ~
svn co https://svn.filezilla-project.org/svn/libfilezilla/trunk libfilezilla
cd libfilezilla
autoreconf -i 
./configure --prefix="$HOME/prefix" --enable-shared --disable-static
make && make install

...on that configure line (line #5) command it does a whole bunch of stuff (apparently successfully), and then finally it stops with this message:

configure: error: GnuTLS 3.7.0 or greater was not found. You can get
it from https://gnutls.org/

It seems like even though GnuTLS was downloaded successfully, extracted, and installed (in a previous series of steps as per the doc), it then cannot be found when it gets to this point.
Note: I didn't attempt to run the make line since the previous line fails.
It doesn't make any sense to me why the libfilezilla configure command can't find GnuTLS. Where can I investigate to see why this isn't working?
Edit
I went back and ran the make commands on GnuTLS and got many errors like this:
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3508: Error: `leaq' is only supported in 64-bit mode
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3510: Error: bad register name `%rax)'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3512: Error: bad register name `%rax)'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3514: Error: bad register name `%rax)'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3516: Error: bad register name `%rax)'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3518: Error: bad register name `%rax)'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3520: Error: `leaq' is only supported in 64-bit mode
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3523: Error: bad register name `%rsp)'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3524: Error: bad register name `%rsp)'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3533: Error: bad register name `%xmm9'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3534: Error: bad register name `%rbx'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3535: Error: bad register name `%xmm10'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3536: Error: bad register name `%rbx'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3537: Error: bad register name `%xmm10'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3538: Error: bad register name `%xmm15'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3539: Error: bad register name `%rbx'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3540: Error: bad register name `%xmm10'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3541: Error: bad register name `%xmm10'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3542: Error: bad register name `%xmm11'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3543: Error: bad register name `%xmm11'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3544: Error: bad register name `%xmm12'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3545: Error: bad register name `%xmm12'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3546: Error: bad register name `%xmm13'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3547: Error: bad register name `%xmm13'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3548: Error: bad register name `%xmm14'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3549: Error: bad register name `%xmm14'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3550: Error: bad register name `%xmm15'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3551: Error: bad register name `%r11)'
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3553: Error: `leaq' is only supported in 64-bit mode
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3554: Error: `leaq' is only supported in 64-bit mode
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3555: Error: `leaq' is only supported in 64-bit mode
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3556: Error: `addq' is only supported in 64-bit mode
coff/aesni-x86_64.s:3557: Error: bad register name `%xmm9'

That is only a small subset of the error messages, but they are all similar to what you see above. How can I solve this?

Is GnuTLS actually installed?  Where?

Could you run pkg-config --print-requires gnutils on a command-line and include the output into the question?

SmellyCat: When I ran that it returned nothing. Please see my EDIT in the question. Apparently my GnuTLS is not installing correctly, but I don't know how to solve.

Per prior edits, there's no need to add conversational material here. Stack Overflow is not a chatroom or a forum. Please keep questions succinct and in a technical writing format.

Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

I found the solution:
pacman -Syu
pacman -S base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gnutls

Then I switched to mingw64 shell.
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gnutls

Then I went back and rebuilt GnuTLS and everything worked.

I suspect you just installed gnutls, but you have probably to install gnutls-dev.
It's possible that libgnutls[VERSION_NUMBER]-dev is installed instead (see here), but that should be fine.

David, specifically what are you proposing I do? I followed the precise instructions in Filezilla and GnuTLS won't install correctly.
